# Ошибка инициализации переменной (current View) потому что она "null"

Tags: android, kotlin

Текущего поля может не быть (то есть в поле может и не быть фокуса) - программа вылетает с ошибкой на строке `currentField.clearFocus()`

**Лог ошибки:**

```
2021-09-10 20:03:52.893 10285-10285/ru.jurvrn.sid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.jurvrn.sid, PID: 10285
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property currentField has not been initialized
    at ru.jurvrn.sid.FirstFragment.getCurrentField(FirstFragment.kt:45)
    at ru.jurvrn.sid.FirstFragment.onViewCreated$lambda-4(FirstFragment.kt:90)
    at ru.jurvrn.sid.FirstFragment.$r8$lambda$a6bb2rdRI450WvNRJFUdj-EKBzo(Unknown Source:0)
    at ru.jurvrn.sid.FirstFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
```

**Часть кода:**

```
public lateinit var currentField: EditText

i -> i.setOnFocusChangeListener { viewCurrent : View, hasFocus ->
        currentField = viewCurrent as EditText

if(!hasFocus)
   correctDateInput()

currentField?.clearFocus()
```

Подстановка `?` не помогает `currentField?.clearFocus()`

Answer (score 2):

Все же в ошибке написано.

> lateinit property currentField has not been initialized

Если вы что-то обозначили как `lateinit` (поздняя инициализация), то будьте добры не обращаться за значением, пока вы сами туда значение хоть раз не запишите. У `lateinit` переменных нет значений по умолчанию.

В вашем конкретном случае пока не сработал хоть раз `setOnFocusChangeListener`, обращаться к `currentField` нельзя.

Здесь подробнее:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables

Comment: ну так как минимум читать умею, даже в теме про суть ошибки написал )) Поэтому нужна помощь как обойти этот момент с неинициализированной переменной. То есть даже если не сработал `setOnFocusChangeListener` чтобы  ошибки не возникало

Comment: @jurvrn, у lateinit переменной можно проверить что она инициализирована.

Comment: понял, изучу. Конечно можно было изначально присвоить переменной значение по-умолчанию, при котором код не выполняется... тогда и ошибки инициализации не будет....но это не грамотно

Comment: В большинстве случаев код с проверками lateinit переменной на инициализацию "попахивает".

Answer (score 0):

с помощью **Eugene Krivenja** и **ЮрийСПб** понял что переменная не просто null, а её вообще как-бы нет, вот что значит не инициализированна.
Решение - проверить инициализацию. Есть два варианта, пока не проверил на практике.

```
if (this::currentField.isInitialized) { currentField.clearFocus() }
```

или 2 вариант - проверять из функции:

```
if (setOnFocusChangeListener::currentField.isInitialized) {
   currentField.clearFocus()
}
```

и 3 вариант - для проверки

```
var currentField: EditText? = null

currentField?.clearFocus()
```

Comment: Третий вариант ваш, нет смысла в `lateinit`, если все что вы с этим делаете -- пытаетесь "обойти".

Comment: у меня  тексту много где встречается currentField, но там это всегда инициализированным приходит. Если не использовать `.isInitialized`, то придется везде знак `?` расставить. Так мне легче один раз всего указать `::currentField.isInitialized`. Или это не правильно ?

Comment: Всего один раз это Ок.

Comment: спасибо за комментарии и помощь